# Why this method takes so much memory?

Tags: java, file, methods, arraylist, mkdir

im trying to solve mistery why should this method for creating directories use so much memory(about 530MB PS Eden Space). After method is executed GC cleans a bit of memory but after that still some remain. But allocated memory allways stays the same (about 700MB Allocated All Pools). It seems that I fail do dereference objects :(

would be nice if someone could give me some advice how to deal with it.

```
public void writeDir(File root, ArrayList<String> hardwareList, ArrayList<String> detectionListFormated, ArrayList<String> siteName, int depth) {
if (depth == 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (depth == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listToDestroy.size(); i++) {
            String toBeFormated = listToDestroy.get(i);
            String toBeTrimmed = toBeFormated.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ß", "ss").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").trim();
            String s = trimLastChar(toBeTrimmed);
            int index = s.indexOf("_");
            if (s.charAt(index + 1) == this.stationNumber) {
                if (s.contains("Manuelle Gruppe")) {
                    File subdir = new File(root, s);
                    File samePath = new File(root, "");
                    subdir.mkdir();
                    detectionListFormated.remove(i);
                    listToDestroy.remove(i);
                    writeDir(samePath, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth);

                } else if (s.contains("Automatische Gruppe")) {
                    File subdir = new File(root, s);
                    File samePath = new File(root, "");
                    subdir.mkdir();
                    detectionListFormated.remove(i);
                    listToDestroy.remove(i);
                    writeDir(samePath, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth);
                } else if (s.contains("Abschnitt")) {
                    writeDir(root.getParentFile(), hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth + 1);
                } else if (s.contains("Stations-Objekt")) {
                    writeDir(root.getParentFile().getParentFile(), hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (depth == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listToDestroy.size(); i++) {
            String toBeFormated = listToDestroy.get(i);
            String toBeTrimmed = toBeFormated.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ß", "ss").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").trim();
            String s = trimLastChar(toBeTrimmed);
            int index = s.indexOf("_");
            if (s.charAt(index + 1) == stationNumber) {
                if (s.contains("Abschnitt")) {
                    File subdir = new File(root, s);
                    subdir.mkdir();
                    detectionListFormated.remove(s);
                    listToDestroy.remove(i);
                    writeDir(subdir, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth - 1);
                } else if (s.contains("Detektions-Objekt")) {
                    writeDir(root.getParentFile(), hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth + 1);
                } else if (s.contains("Stations-Objekt")) {
                    writeDir(root.getParentFile(), hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (depth == 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listToDestroy.size(); i++) {
            String toBeFormated = listToDestroy.get(i);
            String toBeTrimmed = toBeFormated.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ß", "ss").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").trim();
            String s = trimLastChar(toBeTrimmed);
            int index = s.indexOf("_");
            if (s.charAt(index + 1) == stationNumber) {
                if (s.contains("Stations-Objekt")) {
                    File subdir = new File(root, s);
                    subdir.mkdir();
                    listToDestroy.remove(i);
                    detectionListFormated.remove(i);
                    // if added it uses literaly no memory at allSystem.gc();
                    writeDir(root, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth - 3);
                } else if (s.contains("Detektions-Objekt")) {
                    File subdir = new File(root, s);
                    subdir.mkdir();
                    listToDestroy.remove(i);
                    detectionListFormated.remove(i);
                    // if added it uses literaly no memory at allSystem.gc();
                    writeDir(subdir, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (depth == 5) {
        for (String s : hardwareList) {
            String toBeFormated = s;
            String toBeTrimmed = toBeFormated.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ß", "ss").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").trim();
            String a = trimLastChar(toBeTrimmed);
            File subdir = new File(root, a);
            subdir.mkdir();
            this.stationNumber = a.charAt(0);
            // if added it uses literaly no memory at allSystem.gc();
            writeDir(subdir, hardwareList, detectionListFormated, siteName, depth - 1);
        }
    }
    if (depth == 6) {
        for (String s : siteName) {
            String toBeFormated = s;
            String toBeTrimmed = toBeFormated.replace("ä", "ae").replace("ß", "ss").replace("ü", "ue").replace("ö", "oe").trim();
            String a = trimLastChar(toBeTrimmed);
            File subdir = new File(root, a);
            subdir.mkdirs();
            listToDestroy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(detectionListFormated);
            ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>(listToDestroy);
            // if added it uses literaly no memory at allSystem.gc();
            writeDir(subdir, hardwareList, test, siteName, depth - 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: possibly too many files?

Comment: It created like 220 folders. I dont think that this should be problem. I expecting it to create n number of files

Comment: You know that using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` means that there is a new copy of the list whenever you `remove` (or do any other write operation to it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true that because you're not doing this in a loop, you're going to maintain whatever is on the stack below you.  I'm not convinced recursion is the main problem here. I mean you only have 6 levels of depth so at most you have 6 instances on the stack.

Have you considered using the `nio` library to do this instead of the older 'io' library.  One of the [cited problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) with the old `io` library is that it has trouble with large directories, directly related to resource handling.

That being said, this could be done iteratively with a loop or a `Stack` which would result in some memory efficiency as well.  Also, use `else if` on the later `if` statements.

Comment: His variable depth is being changed sometimes. It's having + but - as well... creating the possibility for infinite loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion. This means that within the method you're calling the method itself.

For example: You call the method, then it looks with if statements what depth it is, and under conditions call the method again. But then the first method execution isn't finished, it's just being paused as the new method call is running.
This creates a stack of method calls, nesting so to speak. Every call will have his own variables, all taking up memory.. again and again... you shouldn't call a method within itself!

Comment: Is there better alternative for such kind of task ?

Comment: @Matthijs `you shouldn't call a method within itself!` That is a bold statement! Recursion can have its place.

Comment: True, recursion can have benefits. Not in this case tho, he's adding and substracting from his variable.. probably creating an infinite loop with it.

Comment: Theres the benefit of ease of implementation.  It makes sense to walk down a directory structure recursively (logically) even if it doesn't make sense from a performance standpoint.